# char string not printed properly in c

Tags: c

so i've made a 'guess_the_word' game in c that has a secret word with '-' and'*' and whenever you find a correct character this character substitutes '-' or '*'.However it seems that the secret word is not printed properly..although the first time it seemed to work.When i used a word with 2 consecutive same characters this problem appeared and then for every word i used.

```
  int sel_size, i;
  char select_word[] = "football"; /* the word we are searching*/
  sel_size = strlen(select_word);
  char secret_word[sel_size];

  for (i = 0; i < sel_size; i += 2)
  {
    secret_word[i] = '_';
  }

  for (i = 1; i < sel_size; i += 2)
  {
    secret_word[i] = '-';
  }

  printf("player 2 the secret word is now %s\n", secret_word);/* it should print "_-_-_-_-" but it prints somthing like this"_-_-_-_-0²#*" */
```

Comment: what is the value of sel_size variable?

Comment: Hint: How many characters do you think can `secret_word[sel_size]` store? Why?

Comment: @hariprasad it is obviously undefined...

Comment: your `sel_size` variable is not initialized. I'm surprised it even works on the first time.

Comment: I meant was that caused when he pasted the code here or is it undefined by default in pgm

Comment: guys i am sorry i have it initialized, just forgot passing it here see the edited code.

Comment: char select_word[]="football\0"

Comment: @KBart: There is an implicit null

Answer (score 1):

Strings in C are character arrays *terminated* by the character `'\0'`. You never do this to `secret_word`, so printing it will invoke undefined behavior.

You need to allow for the terminator in the array size:

```
const size_t sel_size = strlen(select_word);
char secret_word[sel_size + 1]; /* Add 1 to fit the terminator. */
```

Then after initializing the characters, terminate the string:

```
secret_word[sel_size] = '\0';
```

Also, that business of incrementing `i` by **2** is also wrong, that will exhaust the array too quickly and lead to undefined behavior as you step outside the array. Don't do that. Just do:

```
memset(secret_word, '_', sel_size);
secret_word[sel_size] = '\0';
```

**UPDATE**: Ah, you want underscores separated by dashes. Then you need:

```
char secret_word[2 * sel_size];

for(size_t i = 0; i < sel_size; ++i)
{
  secret_word[2 * i] = '_';
  secret_word[2 * i + 1] = '-';
}
secret_word[2 * sel_size - 1] = '\0';
```

The above can be expressed more succinctly using pointers, but that might be considered more advanced, so indexing it is.

Comment: He wants it to be `_-_-_-_-_` etc.

Comment: to be honest the perfect solution is using one underscore for each character but they come linked in c by default and i thought using spaces between them while also maintaining the correlation with the select_word could be a problem (example:football as _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _)